# Decrease latency for TCP stack

Tags: c++, c, sockets, tcp, linux-kernel

Hi I have a PC(A) that receive data via TCP and need forward them to other PC(B)server.

The problem is PC(B) server can open only few sessions about 5 and we need to connect it to about 100 clients and we want to do it via PC(A) that read data and add id to data and forward it to server.

for do that I write a simple tcp server(run on PC A), that read data from TCP stack and forward it to PC(B)

I accept the connection on an open socket and forward it to PC(B).

In this PC(A) take about 200 μs to do this data forwarding. I have 3 GHZ * 10 and I use fedora OS, my data is so small.

How I can decrease this latency?

Do I need to change my OS or make any optimization that decreases this latency?

Comment: use UDP instead? if the connection is reliable you don't necessarily need TCP.

Comment: @Mgetz: You'd also lose flow-control etc. if you switch to UDP.

Comment: You might want to read about [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). And with that I mean that you might want to tell us what problem you want to solve, instead of telling us the solution you have.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth aye, but if you're on an extremely reliable dedicated connection that may not be a concern. I've found that people over use TCP in dedicated network situations where another non-reliable protocol might be more appropriate.

Comment: @Mgetz Reliability is not the big concern. UDP packets normally don't get dropped because of transmission errors, they get dropped because of lack of flow control (i.e. buffers fill up and packets gets dropped.)

Comment: What exactly took 200 us? E.g. A:Accept, A:read, A:send to an already open connection, B:read? What latency do you need? Connecting directly to PC(B) will be faster but probably you do not want to do that for some reason. As Joachim wrote, it might be best to describe your actual problem, not just the technical question that came up while trying to solve it.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg tanks I update the question as your comment.

Comment: @PeterG. 200 us is out of accept and sync. it's between PSH,ACK  that receive data to PSH,ASK that send data as I see on Wrieshark.

Comment: @herzlshemuelian: Are you disabling Nagle's algorithm? (`TCP_NODELAY`)

Comment: Where does the 5 come from?

Comment: @Hasturkun yes I did, by setsockopt(listen_fd, SOL_SOCKET, TCP_NODELAY, (int[]){1}, sizeof(int));

Comment: @herzlshemuelian - Eh? 5 sessions on a LAN. How does this make any sense?

Comment: @EdHeal my server need connection to 100 clients but server's stack can open only 5 sessions

Comment: @herzlshemuelian - How can the servers stack just have 5 sessions? Are you confused by the `listen` system call?

Comment: What latency would be acceptable? How big is the data?